# How to couple ListBox size to window size, UWP App C#

Tags: c#, listbox, size, uwp

I am writing a Windows 10 UWP (Universal Windows Platform) app. The app window contains a ListBox and a button. The ListBox should be taking all the space the window offers, and if not all items fit the ListBox, scrollbars should appear.

How can I "couple" the height of the ListBox to eg the window height - 100 ?

The setting the ListBox.Height parameter to this.Height - 100 does unfortunately accomplish nothing, even when done inside a resize event.

Thank you!!

Comment: I don't really have any code related to my question yet, thus my question. The basic program is just a window with a ListBox and a Button. The ListBox should be constrained to the windowsize (and resize with it), while leaving a little space for the button to fit onto the window.

Comment: Set ListBox's `Margin` property.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting only the Margin property does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question clearly, this is what you need -

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox />
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

You don't need to hard-code the height, instead, you use `RowDefinitions` to create two rows inside the `Grid`. The `ListBox` will occupy the *first row* and the `Button` the *second row*.

Note that the *second row* has a height of `100epx` while the *first row* simply fills the rest of the space.

Comment: thank you, works very well! was exactly what I was looking for. I figured it is then even possible to set proportions using eg 2* and so on for Height. [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.rowdefinition.height) very useful!

Comment: @replax or you can set the second row to Auto. So it will give as much as the button needs. :)